# Get variable GET in Yii2 not working

Tags: yii2

Basiclly I have an url that have a parameter.

So, I need to access those parameter using GET. This is the GET that coming:

```
Array
   (
     [r] => hanwa/incoming-pipe/assign-incoming
     [1] => Array
            (
              [min_urut] => 1
              [max_urut] => 44
            )

     [_] => 1496645704980
    )
```

In docs, [docs](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-runtime-requests.html),
We can use like this :

```
 echo $request->get('min_urut');
```

But, I got nothing. Please Advise.

Answer (score 2):

Use Concept of **ArrayHelper class** :-> http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-helper-array.html#getting-values
ex:

```
$data = ArrayHelper::getValue($request->get(), 'Temp.yourvalue.yourindex');
```

Main use of `$request->get()` method mainly returns to you a value from `$_GET`,
 so example is

```
$temp = $request->get('Temp'); // Here $temp variable contains $_GET['Temp']
$data = $temp['yourvaluename'][0];
```

Answer (score 2):

Judging by the fact that you have an array with the key [r] you have an associative array, method get() you will not get it, you need to do it just like this ..

```
echo $request->get()[1]['min_urut'];
```